# Getting a list of currently running processes

Tags: command-line, activity-monitor, macos

I'd like to get a list of all the applications currently running on my machine using the command line. It should be similar to what you get when you open up Activity Monitor and choose to save the list.

I noticed that the `ps -a` command does something similar, but it cuts off the names of the processes.

I'm only interested in the name of the processes, so I don't need all the columns that Activity Monitor outputs.

**Update:** I should have been more clear... I don't want the entire path to the process to be displayed. I just want the name of the process, as it appears in Activity Monitor. For example, `ps` causes `lanchd` to be displayed as `/sbin/launchd` rather than as it is displayed in Activity Monitor (i.e. just `lanchd`). This is a problem because processes that have very long paths end up being truncated (depending on my terminal window's size), and I can't even see the process name.

Comment: I want only my processes...how do I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ps -axc -o comm
```

- `-a` displays processes from all users (or root)
- `-x` includes processes that don't have a controlling terminal
- `-o comm` outputs command paths or names
- `-c` makes `-o comm` output names only

`tell app "System Events" to name of application processes` would list only processes launched from an application bundle.

Comment: This gives me the same info as ephsmith's answer, but it excludes `-bash`, `sort`, `xargs` and doesn't display an error message (which is a good thing). Also, it uses a simpler command, thanks.

Comment: @Senseful, sorry about that :(.  At least I was of some help in addressing your need to save it to a file.

Comment: I want only my processes...how do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Right command, wrong flags.

- Use `ps -Ao comm` if you want process names only.
- Use `ps -Ao command` if you want process names with arguments.

Comment: The first command still outputs the entire path of the process, which causes it to be cut off at the length of my terminal window. For example, in Activity Monitor I see `launchd` in `ps`, it is shown as `/sbin/launchd`. It's not a problem for this process, but it is a problem for those that are nested in many folders. Is there any way to get just the name of the process without its path?

Comment: Ah, yes. You did say "like Activity Monitor" but I didn't think it would matter. Since I see your question's already been answered I'll just leave it at that.

Comment: I want only my processes...how do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned that you'd like to save it to a file.  In the simplest case (the one that you are most concerned about), use

```
ps ax > /path/to/outfile.txt
```

which will print a list of all running processes (with the full name) to the file designated by the path. The ">" redirects the printed output (in overwrite mode) to the file.  Simply issuing `ps ax` will print it to the screen.

*Hint: If you don't feel like typing out a full directory, drag a folder to the terminal to get the path for you and manually complete with the name of the file*

In case you end up wanted some of the other columns at some point... Also, check the man page for ps by typing `man ps` at the command line and look at other options. Here's another example which prints the cpu-usage and memory for each process (in percentages) followed by the command (process):

```
ps ax -o %cpu -o %mem -o command > /path/to/outfile.txt
```

Use

```
# Sort by cpu usage with the 'r' option
ps arx -o %cpu -o %mem -o command > /path/to/outfile.txt

# Sort by memory usage with the 'm' option
ps arm -o %cpu -o %mem -o command > /path/to/outfile.txt
```

**EDIT**

In order to print *just* the command, there are probably more durable approaches, but in a pinch I'd just do what follows. You'll probably notice a bit of cruft near the end related to strings that weren't meant for `basename` (like `-bash`), but the rest of what you want will be there with this quickie.

```
ps ax -o comm | xargs -I % basename % > /path/to/outfile.txt
```

*NOTE:* Some processes that are running are not necessarily executable names.  They could be a straight call to `sh` with a string of commands that follow.

Comment: Upvoting behavior on AskDifferent is strange.  An answer that does not answer the question has a higher vote ranking.  Saving to a file wasn't even addressed :( and the arguments are incorrect for the output the OP requested.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried it but it still outputs the entire path to the process. I'm looking for a solution which *only* outputs the process name and not its path. For example instead of outputting `/sbin/launchd`, it should just output `launchd`.

Comment: Okay.  No biggie.  Just pipe the output of `ps ax` to `basename` via `xargs`.  See edit for more details.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! For the record, I ended up piping it to `sort` too. So the final command is: `ps ax -o comm | xargs -I % basename % | sort`