# Where does OS X store the list of processes?

Tags: macos

Command `ps aux` displays the list, but where does it get it from - kernel itself or launchd?

Comment: It gets it from running processes, there is no list. If you open Activity Monitor in Applications/Utilities it will give you a GUI version of "PS"

Comment: @SteveChambers So it loops through all the RAM?

Comment: No idea *HOW* it works but it enumerates all running processes.

Comment: The kernel has a list of all running processes, indexed by process id. `ps` just lists that table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `ps` command enumerates the mach kernel process listing in a similar manner to how many linux (which don't use mach kernel) expose this as the **/proc** filesystem.

macOS and tvOS and iOS and watchOS all share the same underlying core OS:

- [Getting a list of currently running processes](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/54523/)
- [iOS: Where is /proc/?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/277934/)
- [Getting list of pids and process names](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/296752/)
- [Process list with name and VPRVT](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/85044/)

If you want to see the source code - check out xnu section at https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-4570.41.2/